# select only records with a count of one

Tags: c#, oracle

Searched hi and low and can't seem to find how to do this. I have a table with two columns.

```
Order    route
=====    =====
Order_1   100
Order_1   101
Order_2   102
Order_3   103
Order_4   104
```

I want the result to be,

```
Order_2   102
Order_3   103
Order_4   104
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have tried please.

Comment: SQL? C#? kind of hard to tell what you are after here...

Comment: Sorry about the bad form, i typed it in on my tablet in a hurry. Thanks for fixing. It's a C# sql string using ODP.NET. Shannon's answer worked great. Thanks a million. Awesome site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Order` is a reserved keyword, so I used `order_column` instead.

First the test data:

```
create table order_route_table(order_column varchar2(20)
    , route number);

insert into order_route_table 
select 'Order_1', 100 from dual
union all select 'Order_1', 101 from dual
union all select 'Order_2', 102 from dual
union all select 'Order_3', 103 from dual
union all select 'Order_4', 104 from dual;
```

Then traditionally:

```
select order_column, min(route)
from order_route_table
group by order_column
having count(*) = 1;
```

With analytics:

```
select order_column, route
from (select order_column
        , route
        , count(*) over (partition by order_column) as order_count
    from order_route_table)
where order_count = 1;
```

Results in either case:

```
ORDER_COLUMN              ROUTE
-------------------- ----------
Order_2                     102
Order_3                     103
Order_4                     104
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't actually using the name order. I appreciate the help.

Comment: What does the min function do in this case?

Comment: When using `group by` columns in the `select` clause must either be in the group by or used inside aggregate functions. You don't want route in the `group by` since that would cause both Order_1 rows to be in separate  groups and to display. So `min` gets the minimum route for that group. Each group only has one underlying row, due to `having count(*) = 1` so `min` gets us that route. `Max` would also work.